# Replace mouse click with keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger a mouse click event via a keyboard key down. So instead of the user clicking a button on the website, they could just push the "Shift" key (or any other) and get the same action as if they clicked on the button with a mouse.

I tried a lot of things from SO but nothing seems to be working - any ideas?

---

UPDATE
I am trying to make the function that is triggered when that element is clicked with the mouse be more accessible so that you don't need to only use your mouse but also a keyboard shortcut - so to trigger it on KeyDown - ie

Markup

`<a href="http://www.google.com" class="clickme">LINK</a>`

JS

`jQuery(document.body).on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 16){
    jQuery('.clickme').trigger('click');
    }
    });`

http://jsfiddle.net/0sdesy1x/1/

Comment: There is missing information here. Is the button in focus or is it a keypress anywhere trigger the click? Seems like you just listen for a key press, check the keycode, fire the click event on the input.

Comment: What have you tried? You just need to capture the event, prevent the default action for that event, then do what you want to do via `click()` or `trigger()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I miss understood the question -- here is the proper solution.

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 16){
    window.location = $('.clickme').attr('href');
  }
});
```

What you're looking for is to trigger the default event on your button, which unfortunately is not possible with jQuery, unless they actually click on it. Your solution is to retrieve the "href" value and change the location to the following.

OR

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 16){
    $('.clickme').get(0).click();
  }
});
```

In the second solution we use jQuery to get the jQuery object and to get the actually HTML reference to button reference, then we [click()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) which is a standard JS function.

---

You could keep your click and add this code. This way when the shift key is pressed you can trigger the button click. Or if you really want to replace, then put your button code in the comment section in the example below.

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 16){
    $('<your button class or id here>').trigger('click');
    //or put your button code here...
  }
});
```

You could do something like this.

Comment: Sorry for late response. This is what I try, but no luck
http://jsfiddle.net/0sdesy1x/1/ any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks @Grimbode - but I'm confused. It should be replicating a mouse click. So when I "keydown" the Shift key, the link should be triggered as it would be with a mouse click. Can you please help?

Comment: please see above comment :)

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2012/09/11/back-to-basics-using-keyboard-events-in-javascript/

The above post is a good starter you.

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {

    console.log(e.keyCode);

}, false);
```

the above with give you the keycode for the key pressed - so you can then set an if statement up to check against the key you want to detect to trigger any actions on.